# unknown variable 'file-key-management-filename'

Tags: debian, encryption, mariadb

New installation of Debian 10, with MariaDB 10.3.29. Trying to set up encryption-at-rest, but MariaDB won't start due to an error...

```
2021-07-16 17:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-07-16 17:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-07-16 17:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-07-16 17:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-07-16 17:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-07-16 17:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-07-16 17:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-07-16 17:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-07-16 17:13:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2021-07-16 17:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-07-16 17:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-07-16 17:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-07-16 17:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-07-16 17:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-07-16 17:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.29 started; log sequence number 2195357; transaction id 575
2021-07-16 17:13:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2021-07-16 17:13:17 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-07-16 17:13:17 0 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'file-key-management-filename=/etc/openssl/keys/keyfile.key'
2021-07-16 17:13:17 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

My server.cnf has...

```
[mariadb-10.3]
plugin-load-add = file_key_management
file_key_management_filename = /etc/openssl/keys/keyfile.key
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CTR
```

The above config I have working in a Centos7 system, so I'm baffled as to why it isn't working on Debian10. This message is what I encountered when trying to install encryption in a MariaDB pre-10.1 version that didn't have encryption as an option, but I know encryption is an option after Mariadb 10.1, so it should be available in this package (unexciting installation via apt), right?
I have tried moving the cnf code around, to the [mysqld] and [mariadb] sections to no avail. There are no previous versions of MariaDB hanging around - this is a clean install.

Has anyone encountered this issue and solved it already?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by installing MariaDB 10.4. Not sure why 10.3 wasn't working, but I checked another debian10 system running 10.3 and it was the same issue there too. MariaDB 10.4 seems to be working as expected.